# Why am I getting an unsupportedSchemeError

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am writing a program that uses Mechanize to scrape a student's grades and classes from edline.net using a student account and return the data I need. However, after logging in, from the homepage I have to access a link (called 'Private Reports') which will then dynamically return a page of links to each of the student's classes and respective grades.

When testing I create a new object `my_account` that has several instance variables including the homepage. I pointed new variables to the instance variables for this to be more simple to read):

`result_page = agent.page.link_with(:text => 'Private Reports').click`

I get:

`Mechanize::UnsupportedSchemeError`

But if I were to replace `:click` with `:text` it responds correctly and `result_page` will equal the link's text "Private Reports"

Why does it respond to `:text` correctly but give an error for `:click`? Is there a way to get around this or should I rethink my solution to this problem?

Here's the code:

```
 class AccountFetcher

     EDLINE_LOGIN_URL = 'http://edline.net/Index.page'

     def self.fetch_form(agent)

         # uses @agent of an Account object
         page = agent.get(EDLINE_LOGIN_URL)
         form = page.form('authenticationEntryForm')
     end


     # edline's login form has to have several pre-conditions met before submitting the form

     def self.initialize_form(agent)
         form = AccountFetcher.fetch_form(agent)
         submit_event = form.field_with(:name => 'submitEvent')
         enter_clicked = form.field_with(:name => 'enterClicked')
         ajax_support = form.field_with(:name => 'ajaxSupported')
         ajax_support.value = 'yes'
         enter_clicked.value = true
         submit_event.value = 1
         return form 
     end


     # logs the user in and returns the homepage

     def self.fetch_homepage(u_username, u_password, agent)
         form = AccountFetcher.initialize_form(agent)
         username = form.field_with(:name => 'screenName')
         password = form.field_with(:name => 'kclq')
         username.value = u_username
         password.value = u_password
         form.submit
     end
 end

 # class Account will be expanded later on but here are the bare bones for a user to log in to their account 
 class Account

     attr_accessor :report, :agent, :username, :password
     def initialize(u_username, u_password)
         @agent = Mechanize.new
         @username = u_username
         @password = u_password
     end

     def login
         page = AccountFetcher.fetch_homepage(self.username, self.password, self.agent) 
         @report = page
     end
 end 


 my_account = Account.new('ex_username', 'ex_password')
 my_account.login
 page = my_account.report
 agent = my_account.agent

 page = agent.page.link_with(:text => 'Private Reports').click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the link point to? Ie, what's the href?

I ask because "scheme" usually refers to something like http or https or ftp, so maybe the link has a weird scheme that mechanize doesn't know how to handle, hence `Mechanize::UnsupportedSchemeError`

Comment: I had the same though too, but I found it uses a https protocol for that page, which Mechanize should be able to handle fine, correct? @stoodfarback

Comment: I logged in and tried following the link using irb all at once instead of using the separate classes and various methods but instead of `Mechanize::UnsupportedSchemeError` I received `NoMethodError: undefined method homepage`. Homepage being the page I am looking for the link on

Comment: Just an update @stoodfarback I looked through the pages and quite a few of the links use javascript along with forms which allow you to 'click' them. Using Firebug you can find what form the link uses, fill in the correct action, event, and parameters and submit it and it'll bring you to the new page. That explains the error and I am happy to report all if figured out for now!